# path integrals in polar form.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmcJb.jpg)

[my written answer...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsI4B.jpg)

my question is why did in the book the s(r,ϴ) is integrated with respect to dϴ only and not with respect to rdϴ as i did it, since question mentioned the path and ds=rdϴ so rdϴ should be used, i'm very confused dont know how its possible. may be i'm doing something wrong but not able to under stand what.

Comment: The language of the question is unacceptable to me. One does not integrate a surface.  But I would agree that if it means to integrate $f$ along the curve (presumably with respect to arclength), then you've set it up correctly.

Comment: i kind of understand what you are saying.... the integrand when integrated with respect to the the path on the x-y plane will project on the surface forming the area... in this question like a cylinder ?

Comment: Yes, you're computing the surface area of the portion of the cylinder between the $xy$-plane and the given surface.

Comment: thanks! that cleared a lot of things :)